# How to structure dataframe combinations for regression, without corruption/loss?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression

I have a data set, redacted sample below. My goal is linear regression. My question is: Have I created unintended results, due to how I structured the df, using concat and/or div?

For example, predicting:
(2nd time rating) minus (base time rating) with
the ratio of (percent #1) over (percent #2 ).

From the df below:
((4 wk nprs rating)-(base nprs rating))
with dependent variable: ((active modalities)/(passive modalities))
I've created dataframes, in hopes of efficiency, and run OLS, all below.

Thank you for your insight.

What I've tried:

```
ctr = pd.read_csv('file_path/CTrial Data.csv') #CTR trial
ctr = ctr.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') #converting all to numeric, except NaN where can't
ctr = ctr.fillna(0)                               #replacing NaN with 0's, dropping results in too much loss
```

> Now the difference in pain perception over some time periods.

```
#OSWESTRY Pain Scale (lower back funcion) 
#THIS scale is 0-50
#using absolute value leads to more than max, eg, 4-(-4)=8, not using abs results in negative values  
ctr['Trial_4wk_diff'] = (ctr['osw_4wk'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()   #calculating the difference 
ctr['Trial_12wk_diff'] = (ctr['osw_12wk'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()
ctr['Trial_1yr_diff'] = (ctr['osw_1yr'] - ctr['osw_base']).abs()
```

> Grouping the treating modalities by "active" and "passive" then
> calculating the ratio. These ratings are specifically the perceived
> benefit of each modality.

```
#perceived benefit of active treatment modalities over perceived benefit  of passive modalities
ctr['active'] = pd.concat((ctr['perceived_ben_aerobic_ex'],ctr['perceived_ben_strength_ex'],ctr['perceived_ben_rom_ex']),ignore_index=True)
# 0 NaN
ctr['passive'] = pd.concat((ctr['perceived_ben_meds'],ctr['perceived_ben_rest'], ctr['perceived_ben_surgery'],ctr['perceived_ben_massage'],ctr['perceived_ben_manip'],ctr['perceived_ben_traction'],ctr['perceived_ben_work_restrict']), ignore_index = True)
# 0 NaN
ctr['mods'] = ctr['active'].div(ctr['passive'])  #ratio of active vs passive perceived benefit #Here I simply used .div() 
ctr['mods'] = add_constant(ctr['mods'].fillna(0))
#ctr['mods'].isna().sum()
#4 
ctr['mods'] = ctr['mods'].fillna(0)   #these steps remove the NaN
#ctr['mods'].isna().sum() 
#0
```

> Now running OLS.

```
#OSW 4 week difference with average ratio

from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant

X = ctr['mods'] #modality
y = ctr['nprs_4wk'].abs() #pain scale

model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
model.summary()
```

> output

```
OLS Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  nprs_4wk    R-squared:  -0.000
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: -0.000
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    nan
Date:   Thu, 26 Jan 2023    Prob (F-statistic): nan
Time:   11:14:45    Log-Likelihood: -260.12
No. Observations:   119 AIC:    522.2
Df Residuals:   118 BIC:    525.0
Df Model:   0       
Covariance Type:    nonrobust       
coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
active_avg  0.7351  0.059   12.549  0.000   0.619   0.851
Omnibus:    12.434  Durbin-Watson:  2.044
Prob(Omnibus):  0.002   Jarque-Bera (JB):   14.152
Skew:   0.833   Prob(JB):   0.000845
Kurtosis:   2.718   Cond. No.   1.00

>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> fig = sm.graphics.plot_fit(model, 0, ax=ax)
>>> ax.set_ylabel("NPRS 4 wk diff")
>>> ax.set_xlabel("ratio of perceived ben active vs passive")
>>> ax.set_title("4 wk pain scale vs perceived ben ratio")
```

[image: graph output above]

> Data below, with original missing values:

| pb_meds | pb_rest | pb_surgery | pb_massage | pb_manip | pb_traction | pb_aerobic_ex | pb_rom_ex | pb_strength_ex | pb_work_restrict | osw_base | osw_4wk | osw_12wk | osw_1yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 7 | 19 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 35 | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 18 | 19 | 14 | 18 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 13 | 6 | 8 | 14 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 11 | 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 15 | 15 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 15 | 9 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 15 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
|  | 4 | 3 |  | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 11 | 22 | 17 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 19 | 24 | 16 | 16 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 22 | 16 | 17 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 16 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 19 | 17 | 24 | 27 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 18 | 11 | 16 | 20 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 23 | 21 | 15 | 14 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 15 | 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 24 | 30 | 22 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 |  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 8 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 16 | 14 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 14 | 13 | 16 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 13 | 22 | 15 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 15 | 6 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 14 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 25 | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 33 | 26 | 22 | 19 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 18 | 12 | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 17 | 14 | 8 | 18 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 9 | 12 | 13 |
| 3 | 3 |  | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 13 | 0 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 8 | 9 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 11 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 18 | 18 | 13 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 17 | 11 | 10 | 19 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 17 | 16 | 28 | 28 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 18 | 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 14 | 9 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 24 | 0 | 17 | 25 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 32 | 24 | 26 | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 5 |  | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 19 | 11 | 10 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 26 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 15 | 15 | 13 | 11 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 15 | 18 | 18 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 4 |  | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 17 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 6 | 11 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 15 | 12 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 13 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 14 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 18 | 8 | 10 | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 18 | 15 | 11 | 12 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 12 | 7 | 19 | 14 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 11 | 3 | 11 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 12 | 12 | 9 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 14 | 0 | 8 | 14 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 21 | 19 | 24 | 25 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 25 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 22 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 18 | 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 12 | 20 | 18 | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 21 | 18 | 23 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 13 | 12 | 0 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 23 | 24 | 24 | 23 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 13 | 9 | 0 | 18 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 13 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 31 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 23 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 23 | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 12 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 14 | 11 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 |  | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 16 | 15 | 10 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 17 | 16 | 23 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 11 | 8 | 3 | 14 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 12 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 12 | 11 | 19 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 30 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 21 | 1 | 9 | 8 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 11 | 13 | 19 | 15 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 16 | 19 | 26 | 30 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 35 | 17 | 4 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |  | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 13 | 10 | 23 |
|  | 4 |  | 5 |  |  | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 16 | 20 | 4 | 15 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 18 | 17 | 18 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 17 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 25 | 18 | 29 | 22 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 10 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |  | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 15 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 22 | 19 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 12 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 12 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 11 | 20 | 14 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 21 | 14 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 14 | 20 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 11 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 13 | 16 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 16 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 12 | 9 | 8 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 26 | 17 | 16 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 16 |  | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I can't figure out what you need help with. Every sentence you have with a question mark (in the title or the body of your post) needs clarification. What do you mean by "structure", by "without corruption/loss", by "unintended results", by "better option"? I also can't tell what purpose your code snippets and output serve. Please try to rewrite your post to be concise and clear. If your problem is more conceptual, rather than about implementation, consider asking the question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AlexK Okay, I think this might be an issue on your end, but I appreciate your feedback, and I will consider it. Thank you.
Specifically, this is not about stat, but happens to be using stats. It is about python and pandas input.

Comment: We don't know your research question, we don't know what your unit of analysis is, we don't know what the meaning of your variables is. How can you say this is a problem on my end?!

Comment: @AlexK I think you are stuck on the stats end of it. I include that information because it is the background, but the question is just of how the dataframes are combined. I am asking if they are combined in the best way, or if there are unintended problems created by my methods. It is a pandas/python issue, not stats, I assure you.

Comment: All points above still stand. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @AlexK perhaps, but elsewhere the feedback has been that it is clear. It may just not be something you can interpret. I will give your feedback thought though, and edit accordingly.